# Python: необходимо посчитать в excel таблице количество какого либо одного элемента

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Здравствуйте, только начал изучать питон, и столкнулся казалось бы с небольшой проблемой :(
В таблице 24 колонок по 50 строк, данные в виде цифр от 1 до 5, надо посчитать количество пятерок, четверок и т.д. в каждой колонке. Взял пока parser_cols B, а так надо по всем читать, для начала найти бы сколько встречается пятерок.
Через Counter тоже делал, но не считает. Есть мнение, что поможет конвертировать df в list, но получается только в словарь.

```
file = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname = '1', header = None, na_values=['NaN'], parse_cols = "B")

df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df.head()

five = []
for x in (df1course):
 five.count(5)
 print(x, five)
```

Прошу помочь и указать на ошибки :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример для DataFrame размером 10 x 10:

Создаем "sample DF" (вам этого делать не надо - вы его уже прочитали из Excel файла):

```
In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 6, size=(10, 10)))

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  5  2  5  5  3  4  1  5  3  2
1  5  5  1  4  4  4  5  3  4  4
2  4  1  1  2  1  4  2  1  1  5
3  2  1  1  3  3  2  4  2  5  1
4  3  1  2  2  3  5  3  5  3  5
5  5  2  5  2  4  2  2  3  4  1
6  2  5  1  3  5  2  3  2  2  3
7  2  1  2  2  4  5  1  1  5  5
8  5  1  2  2  2  1  3  5  5  3
9  2  1  4  5  3  1  2  4  3  2
```

Считаем кол-во уникальных значений в каждом столбце при помощи метода [Series.value_counts()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). `df.apply(...)` - применяет указанную функцию к каждому столбцу:

```
In [46]: df.apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[46]:
     0    1    2    3  4    5  6  7  8  9
1  NaN  6.0  4.0  NaN  1  2.0  2  2  1  2
2  4.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  1  3.0  3  2  1  2
3  1.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  4  NaN  3  2  3  2
4  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  3  3.0  1  1  2  1
5  4.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1  2.0  1  3  3  3
```

Разбор ошибок:

`pd.read_excel()` - уже возвращает DataFrame - нет смысла натравливать на него конструктор еще раз.

Comment: до чего же хорошая библиотека, решение одной строкой, благодарю!

Comment: @Python_noob, я бы даже сказал шикарная библиотека ;-)